# Html "Double" Select required

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Olá, estou tentando fazer um form no html onde contém DOIS selects required, porém irei usar apenas um de cada vez, ou seja quando eu selecionar um o outro required deveria passar "batido".
A estrutura é a seguinte:

```
<form>
  <select required>//se esse for selecionado não precisaria selecionar o outro
    <option value="">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select required>//da mesma forma se esse for selecionado o outro não precisa ser também.
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

O resultado desse código não me deixa selecionar apenas 1 select, devo selecionar os dois para que funcione, ou seja eu gostaria de uma estrutura no estilo da lógica "OR" e não "AND" como ocorre aqui.
Se tiver alguma forma de fazer isso sem JS seria melhor ainda.

**OBS: Sim eu preciso de dois SELECTS para fazer isso por questão de intuitividade.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única solução que conheço é através de Javascript.

Criei um método que será executado toda vez que um de seus `select` for alterado, ele receberá o `id` e o `value` do `elemento` alterado.

Caso o `elemento` alterado possuir valor então o outro `select` perderá a sua obrigatoriedade.

Segue exemplo funcionando:

```js
function removeObrigatoriedade(id, valor){
  var lista1 = document.getElementById("lista1");
  var lista2 = document.getElementById("lista2");
  
  if(id=="lista1" && valor != ""){
    lista1.required = true;
    lista2.required = false;
  }
  
  if(id=="lista2" && valor != ""){
    lista2.required = true;
    lista1.required = false;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <select name="lista1" id="lista1" required onchange="removeObrigatoriedade(this.id, this.value)">
    <option value="">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="lista2" id="lista2" required onchange="removeObrigatoriedade(this.id, this.value)">
    <option value="">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  
  
  <button type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar">Enivar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, obrigado único problema do JS é que realmente nem sempre temos suporte ao mesmo infelizmente.

Comment: Entendo sua situação, fico feliz que tenha te ajudado :)